# Get ip address of client browser based on domain name

Tags: c#

I have q requirement of getting the IP Address of clients who have accessed URL based on domain name. For example I am accessing www.google.com from my machine(IP Address : 172.16.58.989) I should log IP Address as 172.16.58.989 on google server. What I am doing In the code is

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
{     
    String ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    return ip;
}
```

But when I access the site using domain name (www.google.com) I am getting the server address. when I am accessing the site with ip address like http://11.11.11.11/aspx/login.aspx I am getting client ip.

Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: `Request.UserHostAddress` returns whatever is returned by `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and should always return a value. Therefore, both conditional pieces of code you've shown here are pointless. If you *just* tried `HTTP_C_FORWARDED_FOR` *first*, and then fell back to `REMOTE_ADDR`, that's the best you can do. And it doesn't (necessarily) tell you the client's IP address - it just tells you the IP address of the closest device to you that's doing any form of forwarding, proxying, translation, etc. If you get an "answer", what will you **do** with the information?

Comment: thanks soner, I want to track the IPAddress of all the clients who have accessed the Site.